# Как из родительского процесса повысить приоритет дочернего?

Tags: c, qnx

Дочерний процесс создается с помощью fork, нужно из родительского процесса повысить приоритет дочернего. Есть функция setprio, но она для нитей.

Answer (score 0):

`setpriority( PRIO_PROCESS, pid, priority );`

pid - вам вернул `fork()`.

см. https://linux.die.net/man/3/setpriority

Comment: Спасибо! Я это использовала, вывела приоритеты с помощью getpriority(), но у родительского и дочернего процессов приоритеты равны 0.

Comment: if (child_pid == 0) {
  printf("Child pt %d\n", getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, child_pid));
  }
else if (child_pid >0) {
   setpriority( PRIO_PROCESS, child_pid,-3 );
   printf("Parent pt %d\n", getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, getpid()));
  
  }

Comment: 0 - это приоритет по умолчанию.  Добавьте паузу в дочернем процессе, чтобы родитель успел поменять приоритет, до того как его распечатает дочерний.

Comment: не помогает, ничего не изменилось